# filling an array with users string input?

Tags: java

Im trying to map digits to a string that the user enters. I cant figure out how to fill my array with the users entered string. im new to java, how do i do this. this was so easy to do in php and I have no idea what im doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ex17 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);     
    String convertString = userInput.next();

    int length = convertString.length();
    String [] stringArray = new String[length];

    for(int j=0; j<length-1; j++){
        stringArray[j] = convertString;
    }

    //stringArray[0] = convertString;

    //for(int i=0; )

    for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++){

        if(stringArray[i].equals("a") || stringArray[i].equals("b") || stringArray[i].equals("c")){
            System.out.println("1");
        }

        if(stringArray[i].equals("d") || stringArray[i].equals("e") || stringArray[i].equals("f")){
            System.out.print("2");
        }

        if(stringArray[i].equals("g") || stringArray[i].equals("h") || stringArray[i].equals("i")){
            System.out.print("3");
        }


    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the input directly int the string array as such:

```
for(int j=0; j<length-1; j++){
        stringArray[j] = userInput.next();
    }
```

your method collected the input once then assigned that value to all spaces of the array

but if you are trying to separate the characters of the string out they can be located by

```
exampleString.charAt(position in string);
```

//position being int number of position in string in string is the location starting counting at 0